# MS Project - Predecessor 'or'

Tags: ms-project

How do I enter 'or' logic into the predecessor field? For instance, task 4 can start when task 1, 2, or 3 ends. We don't know which of 1, 2, or 3 will begin or end first.

Thank you

Comment: Wow, this seems like a basic functionality that should have already been included.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  "Or" relationships aren't supported in MSP (nor in any other mainstream project scheduling tool that I know of.)